# How to send a copy of email to senders address in php contact form

Tags: html, http, sendmail, php

I have a contact form in my website. I need users to send messages to my email, and it does so. I also have a checkbox, which when checked, the users will have the message to the email indicated on the email textbox. My code sends it only to my email, but it doesn't send a copy when the checkbox is checked.

***Contact.html***

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sendcopy" value="Yes" checked/>Copy this message to your mail
```

***Sendmail.php:***

```
$messagebody="Name: ".$name."".PHP_EOL;
$messagebody.="email: ".$email."".PHP_EOL;
$messagebody.="website: ".$website."".PHP_EOL;
$messagebody.="message: ".nl2br($message)."".PHP_EOL;

mail($to,$subject,$messagebody,$headers)or die("The message failed to send");  

if(isset($_POST["sendcopy"]) && $_POST["sendcopy"]=="checked"){
mail($email,$subject,$messagebody,$headers)or die("The message failed to send a copy") 
    }
```

Comment: Why call `mail` twice?  Can't you just add the sender to the BCC?

Comment: @GigaWatt The user might decide not to check the checkbox...BCC will send the mail to the user automatically. i want to give room for choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the snippet `if(isset($_POST["sendcopy"]) && $_POST["sendcopy"]=="checked"){` value of `$_POST["sendcopy"]` you are trying to match with is wrong.
Instead, you can use just `if(isset($_POST["sendcopy"]){` to check if that checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST["sendcopy"]) && $_POST["sendcopy"]=="checked"){
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^
```

wrong. it should be `"Yes"`, because the `value` defined in the form:

```
if(isset($_POST["sendcopy"]) && $_POST["sendcopy"]=="Yes"){
```

Comment: Just `isset` should do it, it will not be set if it is not checked, the value is not important.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['sendcopy']))
```

Comment: What the heck are you talking about?